# mesmerize vs. fascinate (what's the difference in between them, if any, in any aspect?)

Tags: word-choice

mesmerize vs. fascinate

The meaning of the words is similar, but for me 'mesmerize' looks more advanced or more difficult than 'fascinate'.

One of the reasons that I say that is because the word 'fascinate' more common than 'mesmerize'.

If I use the word 'mesmerize' insteand of or in place of 'fascinate', intentionally, will there be any thing for me to keep in mind or is the word entirely interchangeable?

Comment: They have rather different meanings.... So check a dictionary.  Though in some contexts either meaning may be appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about a thing, or an experience, doing it to somebody, they are very similar. But if you are talking about a person doing it, they are very different.

*He fascinated her* does not imply that he was doing anything intentionally, just that she found him fascinating. *He mesmerised her* tends to imply that he was intentionally drawing her into a hypnotic state.

Answer (score 1):

They have similar meanings, but "fascinate" tends to have a more positive connotation and "mesmerize" is somewhat stronger. This reflects [the etymology of "mesmerize":](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mesmerize) it is named after Franz Mesmer, a disreputable doctor who claimed that he could use a form of hypnosis to cure illnesses.

Comment: _Mesmerize_ is a synonym of _hypnotize_. It involves suppression of individual will, so it's not usually positive, whereas _fascinate_ usually is.

Comment: @JohnLawler I've usually heard it just mean "thoroughly drawing in and capturing one's attention"; see [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/mesmerizing) or [the usage of "mesmerizing" in this NYT article](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2023/02/02/travel/things-to-do-bangkok.html), where it clearly isn't about hypnosis or suppressing one's will.

Comment: (I suspect that "hypnotize" is the original meaning, but that it's now been generalized quite a lot.)